# PLSQL_trigger cannot be complied

Tags: plsql

I need to create a trigger that when the last employee of the dept is deleted from emp table, the dept is deleted from the dept table.
emp(empno, ename, deptno)
dept(deptno, dname)

First, I created a procedure that deletes the dept from dept table given a deptno.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE del_dept                                                    
    (v_dno  in  number)  
is  
begin    
    delete from DEPT where deptno = v_dno;  
end;
```

Then I created a trigger that deletes the dept when the last emp in that dept is deleted. I tried to test the trigger by deleting one of the three emps in deptno10, but I got error mesg from command that trigger is invalid and failed re-validation.

```
create or replace trigger del_dept   
after delete on EMP  
for each row  
DECLARE  
    emp_count Number;  
    g_dno Number;   
begin
   SELECT COUNT(:old.ename) INTO emp_count FROM emp group by deptno;  
    FOR i IN 1.. emp_count LOOP  
        IF i = emp_count THEN  
            del_dept(g_dno);    
        end if;           
    END LOOP;  
End;
```

Comment: Hi, it is not good way to delete it with trigger, do it in the form or application which does the **delete** from emp table right after the delete is done

Comment: What is the need of `FOR` loop in this? And when you call `del_dept`, what is the value of `g_dno`?

Comment: My reason for the FOR loop is to check every emp in that dept. If not the last emp, just delete the emp not the dept. I guess I dont need a trigger here to check this condition. The value of g_dno is :old.deptno. I confused IN parameter with OUT parameter. When calling procedure/function, I need to provide the value of IN parameter. Here, g_dno is an IN parameter.Hence, I need to provide that value in the calling routine, which is :old.deptno.

Answer (score 0):

Error `trigger is invalid and failed re-validation` specifies that yor trigger was created with compilation error hence you were not able to test it. This is not a good idea to write a trigger in your case. I can see few issues in you code. So lets first resolve these issues.

When you write the code below, your trigger would be compiled and would be a valid one. So you will not get the error `trigger is invalid and failed re-validation`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER del_dept
   AFTER DELETE
   ON EMP
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   EMP_CNT   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (1)
     INTO emp_cnt
     FROM emp
    WHERE deptno = :old.deptno;

   IF emp_cnt = 0
   THEN
       ---del_dept is your procedure to delete records from dept table 
      del_dept (:old.deptno);
   END IF;
END;
```

But when you would try to execute it you will further get the error:

> ORA-04091: table EMP is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
>
> ORA-06512: at "DEL_DEPT", line 4 ORA-04088: error during execution of
>
> trigger 'DEL_DEPT'

The reason for getting this error is you are trying to `select` from the `table` from which you are `deleting` records and thats not allowed in `oracle`.

The best way for your case is to write a procedure which would delete the records once the last employee data is deleted from your dept table . See below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE del_dept (dept_no NUMBER)
IS
   EMP_CNT   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (1)
     INTO emp_cnt
     FROM emp
    WHERE deptno = dept_no;

   IF emp_cnt = 0
   THEN
      del_dept (dept_no);
   END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your codes and comments!! The homework requirement is to write a trigger instead of a procedure.

Comment: Well i would say if you simply want your trigger to get compiled then you can follow what i did. But when you will run it you will face issue. So if its a homework then its fine else what you are trying to achieve is not the correct way to do it.